# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, onclick, addeventlistener

So I have had this error that's driving me crazy. I'm making my first chrome extension and I can't find what I did wrong with this code snippet:

```
let startButton = document.getElementById("StartBtn")
startButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ //this is the line of code where I get the error
    let recognition = new SpeechRecognition()
    recognition.start()  
})
```

Comment: Are you sure your element's id is `StartBtn`?

Comment: 100% sure, I even copypasted the id and I still get the same error again

Comment: How are you injecting the JavaScript? If you're injecting a content script at `document_start`, the script is most likely executing before the document's body has been created.

Comment: Yeah, but this script should in theory be affecting the start button from the popup.html file. The error might perhaps be that I am targeting the body of the website the user is on and not my popup.html file? That's weird since I set that JS file with the event listener as the script for popup.html, but it might be what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

It means startbutton is null, you probably have a typo in the id

Comment: There isn't a typo in the id, that's why I was so perplexed by this error. "StartButton" is a div, I'm not 100% sure if it's possible to add event listeners on a div but if that isn't the error then I don't really know what's wrong with the code

Comment: Could you share your html?

Comment: Sure, here is the code snippet relevant to the issue
        `<div id="StartBtn">
            <button class="AudioControl" id="startRec"></button>
            <p id="ACT"> Inizia a registrare l'audio </p>
        </div>`

Comment: Are you generating the div with javascript?

Comment: Nope, I created it in the html file